# Compare two arrays of different lengths and exclude matches

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two JSON arrays:

```
{"Array1":[ 
  { "_id": "1234"},
  { "_id": "5678"}, 
  { "_id": "3456"} ]}
```

and

```
{"Array2":[ 
  { "_id": "1234"},
  { "_id": "5678"} ]}
```

How do I compare the two in node.js and return only the difference from `Array1`?

I have attempted the following:

```
if (Array1.every(function (u, i) { return u._id === Array2[i]._id;})) {
    Array1.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Array.prototype.every` for the task of filtering out the identical `_id`s, as that is not its intended function.

Instead, I suggest you use the `Array.prototype.filter` method, along with `Array.prototype.map`, as shown below:

```js
const obj1 = {"Array1":[ 
  { "_id": "1234"},
  { "_id": "5678"}, 
  { "_id": "3456"} ]};

const obj2 = {"Array2":[ 
  { "_id": "1234"},
  { "_id": "5678"} ]};


console.log(obj1.Array1.filter(a1 => obj2.Array2.map(a2 => a2._id).indexOf(a1._id) < 0));
```

**ES5:**

```js
var obj1 = {"Array1":[ 
  { "_id": "1234"},
  { "_id": "5678"}, 
  { "_id": "3456"} ]};

var obj2 = {"Array2":[ 
  { "_id": "1234"},
  { "_id": "5678"} ]};


console.log(obj1.Array1.filter(function (a1) { 
  return obj2.Array2.map(function (a2) { 
    return a2._id; 
  }).indexOf(a1._id) < 0;
}));
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, however, I am getting syntax errors with the lambda expressions on my node.js page.

Comment: @RudolfLamprecht are you using node v6.x? All the above code should work just fine since the coverage of ES6 is really good now.

Comment: @RudolfLamprecht I've added an ES5 version. Should be no problems with that one.